# Redirect to index with url that contains specific number

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have some problems with custom Wordpress htaccess file. I want to get simple redirection from all URLs containing numbers after domain, ex:

```
http://example.com/123 -> to http://example.com
```

And, my second problem is almost the same, but for 1 specific 4-letter URL, ex:

```
http://example.com/4554 -> to http://example.com/
but http://example.com/4555 (other 4-letter nubmer should fail)
```

I've already tried many things, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{3}$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
```

But it doesnt work. 
Usual Wordpress htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\d{3}|4554)/?$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Well, that was easier than I expected. Thanks!